# Need some help understanding backreferences in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, backreference

I was working on a coderbyte problem where I output the number of occurrences of a character along with the corresponding character.  For example "wwwggopp" would return 3w2g1o2p. I was able to solve it but  I compared my answer to someone else's and they came up with the following:

```
def RunLength(str)
   chunks = str.scan(/((\w)\2*)/)
   output = ' '
   chunks.each do |chunk|
      output << chunk[0].size.to_s + chunk[1]
   end
   output
end
```

I get most of the code but what exactly is happening here?

```
 (/((\w)\2*)/)
```

I understand that \w refers to any character and \2 is a 'backreference' and * refers to 0 or more instances...but together, I'm not sure what it means, mostly because I don't know really know what a backreference is and how it works.  I've been reading about it but I'm still struggling to grasp the concept.  Does the \2 refer to the "2nd group" and if so, what exactly is the "2nd group"?

Comment: that \2 will never match because there is no second capture group at that point.

Answer (score 3):

[Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) recall what was matched by a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). A backreference is specified as a backslash (`\`); followed by a digit **indicating the number of the group** to be recalled.

Your regular expression broke down:

```
(           # group and capture to \1:
  (         #   group and capture to \2:
    \w      #     word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
  )         #   end of \2
  \2*       #   what was matched by capture \2 (0 or more times)
)           # end of \1
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that plain parentheses are a capture group; parentheses with question mark syntax (`(?:...)`, `(?=...)` etc) are not capturing.

Comment: So the first parenthesis or \1 captures all the occurrences of a character, e.g ['www'] ['gg'] ['o'] ['pp'] in "wwwggopp"and the 2nd parenthesis or \2 captures 1 character from the \1 group e.g. ['w']['g']['o']['p'].  If that's the case, is it safe to assume that a plain parenthesis will always capture all occurrences of a character?

Comment: No, plain parentheses will capture whatever is in them. If you have a string `"The dog is running"`, `(dog)` captures `"dog"`, `(..g)` captures `"dog"` or `"ing"`, `(\s)` would capture each whitespace individually, `((.)..\2)` would capture `"nnin"` or `" is "` (repetition of the same character after two intervening characters).